# Ternary execution of functions

Tags: javascript, linq

I'm working on a project that will do a lot of processing of numbers in arrays. To try and encapsulate some condition logic I've done something like

//ignore the fact that it's a bad idea to extend JS base types

```
Array.prototype.ifThenElse = function (statement, funcA, funcB, args) {
        return (statement) ? funcA(args) : funcB(args);
};
```

So this takes a boolean expression and executes the funcA if the bool is true, and executes funcB if it is not.  The kicker here is that args should be the array itself.  So here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xG2e/5/) and the code:

```
  var newData = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    Array.prototype.ifThenElse = function (statement, funcA, funcB, args) {
        return (statement) ? funcA(args) : funcB(args);
    };
    function timesTwo(arr) {
         return arr.map(function (val, ix) {
            return val * 2;
        });
    };
    function timesThree(arr) {
        return arr.map(function (val, ix) {
            return val * 3;
        });
    };

     var nArray = newData.ifThenElse(newData[0] < newData[1],timesTwo,timesThree,newData);
     //console.log('This is the nArray ' + nArray);


     var expression = !!0 > 100;
     var expression2 = !!100 > 0;
     var dData = newData.ifThenElse(expression, timesThree, timesTwo, newData);
     var eData = newData.ifThenElse(expression2, timesThree, timesTwo, newData);
     console.log(dData);//2,4,6,8 <=expression is false, timesTwo called
     console.log(eData);//3,6,9,12 <=expression is true, timesThree called
```

I don't want to hardcode the functions that can be passed to `ifThenElse, but I'd also looking to see if there's a clever solution to make this more LINQ-like and somehow have newData automatically passed as the last parameter of the method

Comment: `//ignore the fact that it's a bad idea to extend JS base types` Well, it isn't a fact, so there's nothing to ignore.

Comment: "*The kicker here is that args should be the array itself.*" You mean like this? `return (statement) ? funcA(this) : funcB(this);`

Comment: @cookiemonster well, I might say that was embarrassingly simple

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` in a method called from an object generally refers to the object on which it was called.

Because your `Array.prototype` method is called on an Array, the value of `this` in the method is a reference to the Array.

So just pass `this` to pass the Array.

```
return (statement) ? funcA(this) : funcB(this);
```